# PHP remote SQL Server authentication issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-authentication

I have a named instance of SQL Server 2019 Developer Edition running on my host Windows 10.
Using SSMS I can log in locally using Windows Auth or a SQL Server account.

Whenever I try this from my Laravel site running on my Linux VM running under Hyper-V (using the sa account), the authentication fails.

```
SQLSTATE[28000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'sa'.
```

This only started failing recently after KB5015807 was installed on my Windows10 host, uninstalling the patch makes the authentication work again.

Are there any known issues/changes in this patch for SQL Server auth?

UPDATE 1 (7th Sept 2022):
So, I've since moved the linux VM onto VMWare ESXi 6.5 (to work around Hyper-V).
I'm still getting the same error, though I did find an error item in the logs:

```
Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: An attempt to login using SQL authentication failed. Server is configured for Integrated authentication only.

Source      MSSQLSERVER
Category        (4)
Event       18456
Computer        [MyHostMachine]
```

Of course, it is configured for mixed mode.

```
select serverproperty('IsIntegratedSecurityOnly')
```

returns 0 and my sa password works when logging in through SSMS. Any ideas?

UPDATE 2 (12th Sept 2022):
Got my dev machine working under ESXi, Laravel doesn't like port 1433 being specified, also updated the production server (which still works).
Updated my old Hyper-V VM, which still doesn't work, so definitely a Windows/Hyper-V issue - hopefully a future patch will resolve it.

Comment: There is usually more information on login failures in the SQL Server error log

Comment: @Charlieface, I'm not seeing anything about failed logins

Comment: Possibly a TLS failure? What happens if you connect using SSMS from the same machine?

Comment: Did you enable the TCP netlib? It isn't enabled by default om dev edition.

Comment: I remember someone over on Spiceworks reporting issues with networking as well. I know this doesn't answer the question, but you're not alone.

Comment: @Charlieface - Using SSMS from the same machine works fine with AD or SQL auth.

Comment: @TiborKaraszi - all protocols are enabled (tcp/ip,named pipes & shared memory).

Comment: This link seems to describe my issue, though the suggested fix doesn't work: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/947052/kb5015807-windows-10-hyper-v-networking-issues-iss.html

Comment: @SteB can you share the connection string application is using to connect to SQL Server? just  mask the sa's password ofc...

Comment: @AlekseyVitsko sorry, I have no idea how to get the connection string out of Laravel (or even if you can). Tried my production DB settings on my dev VM - still no joy.

Comment: Ran my Hyper-V VM for first time since September (now running my dev VM on VMWare Esxi), my laravel project ran OK first time. Can only assume MS fixed whatever they broke in a new update.

Answer (score 0):

> Whenever I try this from my Laravel site running on my Linux VM running under Hyper-V (using the sa account), the authentication fails.

**Never** connect an Application to a SQLServer database using the "sa" account!

*Always* keep the "biggest" and "best" Tools for *yourself* ...
... to clean up the mess made by *other* People and Processes.

Comment: the production site connects with a custom SQL Server login (never sa), my dev machine connects with neither, but only under Hyper-V. Under ESXi, they both work (sa & custom logins).